# Zen-coding child numbering

Tags: html, nested, emmet

I was searching a lot for this, maybe someone know a good answer for this.

I tried to use this:

`(.span3>img[src="/images/img_$.png"])*4`

But this creates:

```
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_1.png" alt="" /></div>
```

And I see the logic in this, why I got this result, but is there any way to use numbering in a child element, to get `img_2`, `img_3` and `img_4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.span3*3>img[src="/images/img_$.png"]
```

Or

```
.span3*3>img[src=/images/img_$.png][alt]
```

Output is

```
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_2.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="/images/img_3.png" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect! 
I am new with Zen-coding, I've get used to Stylus pre-processor, but I have a project where I can't use that.