# Zen code- writing style - image src change

Tags: html, emmet

How can i get this output from zencoding

```
<div class="span1"><img src="/images/1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span2"><img src="/images/2.png" alt="" /></div>
```

Comment: Hmm... Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16414333/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div.span$*2>img[src=/images/$.png][alt]
```

produces

```
<div class="span1"><img src="/images/1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="span2"><img src="/images/2.png" alt="" /></div>
```

See https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/ for syntax description.

Comment: You can combine attributes into a single set: `img[src=/images/$.png alt]`

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok Yes, I realized that after posting. But it's not as clear, IMO.